# jQuery Tools Scrollable, Firefox Implementation Issue

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-tools

I am attempting to implement the jQuery Tools Scrollable Example from here:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

and I am having a problem getting this to function in jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/NY5ax/

I have included all of the necessary resources listed in the documentation including:
jQuery 1.6.4 and jquery.tools.min.js

I am obviously missing something. If someone could check it out I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Add either `<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>` to the markup or re add the plugin to the managed resources. That got it to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NY5ax/22/</s>

### Edit

This plugin doesn't seem to work for me in Firefox 7.01. Works in Chrome and IE9.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/one-sized.htm doesn't work either.

### Edit 2

Just tried with FF 10. Still doesn't work. I'd file an issue @ https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools if there isn't one already there.

Comment: again its an issue with the Tabs not functioning, the previous and next buttons do function

Comment: It seems to be Firefox. Works fine for me in other browsers.

Comment: thanks! This appears to be the case with Firefox.  Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/pZ6WT/

Comment: Just thought I'd add that there is an issue filed here: https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/556

Comment: I opened a similar issue as well lol:  https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/659

Comment: have you ever checked out Ariel Flesler's Serial Scroll it looks like it does the same thing:  http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html  I have it here as well:  http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/nJu5D/

Comment: @Paul, As you have just learned, jQuery Tools is junk.  It was developed for jQuery 1.4.2 well over a year ago and it's now full of bugs that pop up in newer browsers.  A major overhaul has been discussed for the last several months but the developer has not been able to find enough help.  He says that when jQT is finally updated, it will not be backward compatible with code anyone wrote for previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NY5ax/14/). Actually you were missing some css styles and css files, I've included them and now it is working like a charm.

Comment: for some reason the Tabs do not scroll the same as the prev/next buttons